# two divs in one line not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, inline

I want two div to be in one line
It's working in IE but it's not working in safari and iPhone.
In Safari and I phone it shows each div in a line.

```css
.post-short-footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100% !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  min-width: 500px
}

.read-more-post {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 5%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

.read-more-post a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}

.post-short-meta-container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 95%;
  line-height: 1.3;
  vertical-align: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.post-short-meta-container span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-short-footer">
  <div class="read-more-post"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" style="color: black;" aria-hidden="true">></i></div>
  <div class="post-short-meta-container"><span style="font-size: 13pt; color: black;">Vacuuming</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any problems. Everything is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope this work for you.

```
div is block element, where span is inline element. 

<div class="post-short-footer">
      <span class=""><i class="fa fa-caret-right" style="color: black;" aria-hidden="true">></i></span>
      <span class=""><span style="font-size: 13pt; color: black;">Vacuuming</span></span>
    </div>
```